# How you can use your public method in a DomainController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have writen a method to generate a email address 'automatic'. But how can I use it in my `DomainController`?

I Have this in my `DomainController`

```
sporters.Add(new Sporter
{
   EmailSporter = sporter.Email()       
});
```

And this is my public method, but I can't use it in my `DomainController`, my `DomainController` is just a class.

```
public string Email(string vn, string fn)
{
    vn = Voornaam.ToLower();
    fn = Familienaam.ToLower();

    EmailSporter = $"({vn}).({fn})@student.telenet.be";

    return EmailSporter;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]. It is not clear where that code runs nor how nor what you actually want to achieve

Comment: Can we see the class you defined Email method? What is the type of sporter varaible?

Comment: So what if it is just a class? Just create an instance of your class and use it: `var dc = new DomainController(); dc.NameOfMethodYouWantToUse();`

Comment: Why does your `Email` method have parameters if you don't use them? *Part* of your issue is that you're calling `Email()` without specifying any parameters (and it expects two)... But they are useless/unused anyways. Declare `vn`/`fn` as local variables and remove the parameters from the method signature. Where did you declare `sporter`? What type is it? Show its declaration.

Comment: `If your method is defined inside `DomainController` and you are trying to use(call) it in the same `DomainController`, Simply use `Email("a","b");`